# Read single cell values from httppostedfilebase Excel File

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

I have an Excelfile that the client send to server as httppostedfilebase and I need to know how I can read values from this file.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowExcelFile(GetExcel model)
    {
        var file = model.Files[0]; 
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file.FileName);
        var fileName = Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName);
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(info))
            {
                //Read some cell value, how?
            }
        } 
        return View("ShowExcelFile");
    }
```

My model:

```
public class GetExcel
{

    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }

    public GetExcel()
    {
        Files = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    }
}
```

My view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowExcelFile", "ShowExcel", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Files, new { type = "file", name = "Files" })<br />
     <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />
}
```

I really don't now how to do this, I have tried Excel Data Reader but it can't read formula values. I just wan't to read a cell value from this excelfile send from the client

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you use EPPlus library. To get the value you need to write smth like that

```
public void Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
      package.Load(file.InputStream);

     var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
     var cellValue = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex].Value;
     var formulaValue = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex].Formula;
}
```

Comment: I get FileNotFoundException. It's trying to look in a path that doesnt exist

Comment: Place a break point in your `ShowExcelFile`. Is `model.Files[0]` null? If so, it is because you are not posting `List<HttpPostedFileBase>` in the view. Once you fix that, you should be able to read the path.

Answer (score 1):

Lets put this inside your controller action u will get the file:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult ShowExcelFile()
    {
        // For getting the file that is Uploadeded.
        HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload = Request.Files["Files"];
        byte[] data;
        using (Stream inputStream = fileUpload.InputStream)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
            if (memoryStream == null)
            {
                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                 data = memoryStream.ToArray();

                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }

        return  Json(new { }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: I get the file with Model.Files[0] already. The problem is reading it

Comment: And how do I get my Cell values out from that?

Comment: @Ni3 the problem here that the question was not pretty clear. And no information about EPPlus package used for reading.

Comment: You need to use SpreadSheetGear that converts that byte data to DataTable

Comment: @Ni3 suppose it's an overhead to use such monster (and it's not free, right?) for his needs. EPPlus will cover majority of his requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few prolems with the how the controller and view are implemented . For example, your ActionResult expects `List<HttpPostedFileBase>`, but the view is posting `HttpPostedFileBase`.

***However***, beyond that, inside using of `package`, try:

```
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
worksheet.Select(new ExcelAddress("A1")); //there is more than one way to set this
string cellVal = (string)worksheet.SelectedRange.Value;
```

Comment: The problem is when I use using package the path is not correct to the file